# Restrict choosing past date in p:calander while editing using p:cellEditor

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want user to restrict choosing past date(i.e before current date) in p:calander while editing using p:cellEditor

```
<p:column style="width:120px;" sortBy="#{v.promoDate}" headerText="Action Date">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{v.promoDateString}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:calendar readonlyInput="true" value="#{v.promoDate}" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Bean onEdit method

```
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    setEditMode(true);
    foodPromoDTO = (FoodPromotionDTO) event.getObject();
    Map<String, Object> sessMap = CommonUtil.getSessionMap();
    SessionDTO sessionDTO = (SessionDTO) sessMap.get(WebConstants.SESSION_DTO);
    String eid = sessionDTO.getUserDetailsDTO().getEid();
    Integer roleCountryId = sessionDTO.getLoggedinUserRoleCountryId();
    getDashboardService().addFoodPromotion(foodPromoDTO, eid, editMode, roleCountryId, sessionDTO.getLoggedinCountryCode());
    myFoodList = getFoodPromoList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code that does just what you need:

**The View**

```
<p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />

<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dataTable value="#{celleditionMBean.list}" var="item" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="dtVar">

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{celleditionMBean.onEdit}" process="date" />

        <p:column style="width:120px;" headerText="Action Date">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.promoDate}" >
                        <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="date" pattern="MM dd, yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:calendar id="date" readonlyInput="true" value="#{item.promoDate}" pattern="MM dd, yyyy" mindate="#{celleditionMBean.current}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**The Managed Bean**:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CelleditionMBean implements Serializable {

    private List<SimpleBean> list;

    private Date current;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        current = new Date();
        list = new ArrayList<SimpleBean>();
        list.add(new SimpleBean(11, "A"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(22, "B"));
        list.add(new SimpleBean(33, "C"));
    }

    public void onEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Changed");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public List<SimpleBean> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<SimpleBean> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Date getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Date current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

}
```